# wpf popup wrong placement wrong size

Tags: wpf, popup, popupwindow

The `Popup` I am trying to create is in the wrong size and t doesn't seem to care about the placement I've set at all.

```
<Popup Name="mypopup" Width="700" Height="600" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <Grid Background="#FFFFFFF1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.606*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.394*"></ColumnDefinition>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="70"></RowDefinition>
             <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Comment: I don't see any placement setting. See [Defining the Popup Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749018.aspx#DefiningPopupPosition).

Answer (score 0):

Popup usually does not add as a visual child. Instead it appears in air without any connection with visual. So I suggest you to use HorizontalOffset and VerticalOffset attributes to position the popup. Also there is PlacementMode option to position the popup.

[Anatomy of Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613596.aspx)

Regarding the popup size, I suggest to set size to the immediate child (Grid in your case) inside popup instead of setting height and width to popup.

Comment: Yeah I already tried to set the size of my grid but it gave me the same results, no difference what so ever :(